# Implicit cursor and NO_DATA_FOUND exception

Tags: sql, oracle, exception

I have the following `PL/SQL` code:

```
BEGIN
  FOR c IN (SELECT ...) LOOP
     <code1>;
  END LOOP;
  <code2>;
EXCEPTION WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
  NULL;
END;
```

This code should run **code1** multiple times within a loop and upon finishing this loop **code2** should be executed. Otherwise if SELECT query does not find data then I expect this should raise an exception and overstep **code2**, but this is not happening. Why?

Comment: No that's not what is supposed to happen! if there is no data, then loop runs 0 times - i.e. it skips and executes code2

Comment: Ok, that's how it is although I expected that 0 records from SELECT statement will raise an exception, so how can I solve my problem to avoid execution of code2 if there's no records?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NO_DATA_FOUND` is thrown by statements that must return exactly one row but do not find a matching row, e.g.

```
DECLARE x NUMBER;
BEGIN
  SELECT foo INTO x FROM bar WHERE xyz='abc';
EXCEPTION
  WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
    ...
END;
```

In your case, you could do the following:

```
DECLARE foundSomething BOOLEAN := FALSE;
BEGIN
  FOR c IN (SELECT ...) LOOP
     foundSomething := TRUE;
     <code1>;
  END LOOP;     
  IF NOT foundSomething THEN
    NULL;  -- handle the situation
  ELSE
    <code2>;
  END IF;
END;
```

Comment: Ok, that's the classic aproach with boolean flag (if entered the loop), but I expected that in PL/SQL there's something else like IF sql%rowcount or something else when there's SELECT returning more thatn one row.

Comment: Also how to find the number of records fetched by SELECT not using explicit iterator inside LOOP?

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no direct way to get the number of fetched records in a cursor for loop - `sql%rowcount` doesn't work in that case, as you have surely found out yet.

Comment: Just wondering, you said that NO_DATA_FOUND is thrown by statements that must return exactly one row. How Oracle know whether this statement will return one or more rows (OK, if search field is PK or UQ column) but from your SELECT statement above (SELECT foo INTO x FROM bar WHERE xyz='abc') one cannot know that in advance.

Comment: @sbrbot: Those statements (`SELECT ... INTO ... `) must return one row because of the `INTO` clause. You expect exactly one result to store in `x`. If there is no such row, `NO_DATA_FOUND` will be thrown. If there is more than one row, `TOO_MANY_ROWS` will be thrown. I.e. **must** in that case means that you, the developer, must take care to craft the statement in a way that it returns exactly one result.

Answer (score 1):

No, that's not what is supposed to happen.

If there is no data, then loop runs 0 times - i.e. it skips code1 and executes code2.

You can define explicit cursors and do the checks for data unavailability like this:

```
DECLARE
  cursor cur is select 1 a from dual where 1 = 1;
  type tab is table of cur%rowtype;
  v tab;
BEGIN
  open cur;
  loop
    fetch cur bulk collect into v;
    if v.count = 0 then
        raise no_data_found;
    end if;
    dbms_output.put_line('Code1');
  end loop;
  close cur;
  dbms_output.put_line('Code2');
EXCEPTION 
  WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
    dbms_output.put_line('Error');
END;
/
```

You can easily extends this code to do other things such as divide fetch into batches etc.

Comment: you transformed my implicit cursor into explicit one and then you checked v.COUNT attribute (number of forws in cursor). Is something like this possible with implicit cursor?

Comment: @sbrbot - You can use a flag variable to set inside the loop, check after the loop and raise the exception if needed as the other answer suggests. There is no builtin mechanism AFAIK.